# fdisk shows /home has 430GB while du -h only 326GB

Tags: gparted, home-directory, disk-usage, fdisk

My /home partition has 430GB as rightfully shown by GParted or fdisk -l. However, if I look at

```
sudo du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
```

there is only 326GB in the disk:

```
351G    .
326G    ./home
7.1G    ./var
6.4G    ./snap
6.2G    ./usr
2.2G    ./opt
848M    ./lib
196M    ./boot
16M ./etc
13M ./bin
12M ./sbin
3.7M    ./root
```

I cannot see where the memory that is missing is allocated or gone.. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` (disk usage) shows how much of the filesystem (disk partition) that is used.

`fdisk` and `gparted`shows the size or the partiton.

You can also use `df -h` (disk free), it shows info like this:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              497M  231M  267M  47% /boot
....
```

there are other options to df too, see `man df`.